# Why do i get this error in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Bubble2()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25). _
        Select

    Selection.Name = "zooky"
    Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text.................."
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10). _
        ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    Range("P5").Select
End Sub

Sub FlipFlop2()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("zooky")
        .Visible = Not .Visible
    End With
End Sub
```

Excel tells me that there is no Element with that name at this line:  With ActiveSheet.Shapes("zooky")

What i want to do is that if i click on my element excel should draw a cloud shape and when i click the element again it should remove that same cloud again

any ideas?

Comment: You need to name the `Shape`, not the `Selection`.

Comment: Hmm nope @Comintern, I can't see the problem - paste the code into excel and it works fine for me in excel 2016.

Comment: @NickDewitt - Ah, you're right.  I missed the `Select` on the line continuation.

Comment: Code works successfully in Excel 2013.  Make sure the sheet with the shape named "zooky" is the Active Sheet.

Comment: It works fine in Excel 2010 , You may have changed the sheet or workbook before calling subroutine FlipFlop

Comment: ok it works. Another question: if i just duplicate the code and change the cordinates of the shape and name it bubble3 and flipflop3 the following happens: if i lunk bubble it makes a new bubble at the "new cordiantes" but when i assign flipflop3 to it it kinda creates and hides the old bubble instead of making a new (like when only doing bubble3)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to avoid using `Select` and `Selection`, instead you should define a `Shape Object` and `Set` it to your created Shape, (see code below).

```
Option Explicit

Public Shp As Shape

Sub Bubble2()

    ' set object reference to new created Shape
    Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25)

    With Shp
        .Name = "zooky"
        .Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text.................."
    End With

    With Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10)
        With .ParagraphFormat
            .FirstLineIndent = 0
            .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
        End With
        With .Font
            .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
            .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
            .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
            .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Fill.Transparency = 0
            .Fill.Solid
            .Size = 11
            .Name = "+mn-lt"
        End With
    End With

    Range("P5").Select

    ' just for testing
    'Call FlipFlop2

End Sub

Sub FlipFlop2()
    With Shp
        .Visible = Not .Visible
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That Global should really be a parameter to `FlipFlop2`

Comment: @TimWilliams maybe i'm too tired today (the kids), but not following your comment, can u edit ?

Comment: Sorry - looking again at `FlipFlop2` it does look like it might be called repeatedly, so might need that global to persist the shape reference...

Comment: i tried but it tells me that Shp doesnt exist as Objectvariable or as With-block variable

Comment: works. thank you. Just one more thing. if i assign the FlipFLop2 macro to some object it tells me that Shp does not exist. because it was obviously not created yet. So what i have to do now is assign the bubble2 sub to 1 obj and then the flipflop2 sub to another object to hide the bubble again. is there any way to avoid it? Like just call flipflop2 when bubble was called before and if not just call bubble? Maybe i can add some state inside the bubble sub so i can ask for it when running the macro?

Comment: strange.. if i add the buble just once i can always call flipflop and it shows and hide the bubble correctly. I just need that behaviour but just without the initial creation

Comment: @zooky i am not following you, you want to use the `Sub FlipFlop2` before the creation of the shape ? Maybe it's better if you open a new post, add your current code, and explain there what is it you are trying to do. This post was about resolving an error you got

Comment: @zooky mark as "Answer" as I think my answer helped you solve your post